# crossplane: error: failed to build package: not exactly one package meta type

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, infrastructure-as-code, crossplane

I followed [the Crossplane docs about creating a Configuration Package](https://docs.crossplane.io/latest/concepts/packages/#create-a-configuration) and created the following `crossplane.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: meta.pkg.crossplane.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: crossplane-eks-cluster
spec:
  dependsOn:
    - provider: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2
      version: ">=v1.1.1"
    - provider: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-iam
      version: ">=v1.1.1"
    - provider: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-eks
      version: ">=v1.1.1"
  crossplane:
    version: ">=v1.15.1-0"
```

I have a Composition and a XRD in the `apis` directory, but when I run `crossplane xpkg build --package-root=/apis` I get the following error:

```
$ crossplane xpkg build --package-root=apis/
crossplane: error: failed to build package: not exactly one package meta type
```

The docs state nothing what I can do and also google didn't help.

Comment: Why is this closed, along many other crossplane questions? There is exaclty 0 question about crossplane on ServerFault or other Stackexchange communities - nor is there a CI/CD tag (where there is a Community for it here along other Cloud Communities)? Also this question seems to help many people - I don't get it. In this reasoning there should be closed any Docker, Kubernetes, CI/CD (GitHub, GitLab - also a Community), Ansible, etc. etc. questions. Really annoying. Sorry to rant here, but don't really know where to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I tested the other option I found to create a Configuration: There are templates one could use to create the crossplane.yaml using the [crossplane CLI's new `beta xpkg init` command](https://docs.crossplane.io/latest/cli/command-reference/#beta-xpkg-init). I ran the following:

```
crossplane beta xpkg init crossplane-eks-cluster configuration-template
```

The resulting `crossplane.yaml` had multiple `metadata.annotations` like this:

```
apiVersion: meta.pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: your-configuration
  annotations:
    # Set the annotations defining the maintainer, source, license, and description of your Configuration
    meta.crossplane.io/maintainer: You <myself@me.io>
    meta.crossplane.io/source: github.com/your-organization/your-repo
    # Set the license of your Configuration
    meta.crossplane.io/license: Apache-2.0
    meta.crossplane.io/description: |
      This is where you can describe your configuration.
    meta.crossplane.io/readme: |
      This is where you can add a readme for your configuration.
spec:
  # (Optional) Set the minimum version of Crossplane that this Configuration is compatible with
  crossplane:
    version: ">=v1.14.1-0"
  # Add your dependencies here
  dependsOn:
    - provider: xpkg.upbound.io/crossplane-contrib/provider-kubernetes
      version: "v0.12.1"
    - function: xpkg.upbound.io/crossplane-contrib/function-patch-and-transform
      version: "v0.3.0"
```

**So simply add the annotations and the error is gone.**

This makes a lot of sence, since a Configuration's user should be able to know, who's responsible for the CRDs. But the error message should maybe be enhanced.